# fatal error: 'libcouchbase/cbft.h' file not found

Tags: pip, couchbase, libcouchbase

```
fatal error: 'libcouchbase/cbft.h' file not found
```

Error while installing couchbase.
command used: `sudo pip install couchbase`.

Answer (score 1):

installing **libcouchbase** is required.

(in my case, updating libcouchbase did the trick)

For Mac:

> brew unlink libcouchbase 
>   brew install libcouchbase
>   sudo pip install couchbase

Answer (score 1):

`libcouchbase/cbft.h` is a C header file recently added to libcouchbase in order to support the Couchbase Full Text (cbft) Search developer preview in Couchbase Server 4.5. It appears in this instance that you have previously installed an older version of libcouchbase without full text support and you are trying to install a new version of the Couchbase Python client *with* full text support. The Couchbase Python client relies on libcouchbase to handle the full-text queries and needs the `cbft.h` header file to allow it to call into libcouchbase.

The answer in the case (as you identified yourself) is to update your version of libcouchbase. On OSX this can be done using brew, on supported Linux platforms you can add our package repositories & install using apt-get/yum, and on Windows you can download our prebuilt binaries - you can find details on how to do this in the documentation (http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/c/start-using-sdk.html).